# Hard Problems in Pairings

Tags: pairings, hardness-assumptions

I want to know whether the following problem is considered as a hard problem in complexity theory or not?

Given $g,g^a,g^b \in G_1$ (for unknown $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\ast}$), compute $e(g,g)^{ab^2}\in G_2$.

If yes, could you please help me to know the name of this problem in the literature?

Answer (score 2):

There is a generalisation of the [Diffie-Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem) to multi-linear groups known as the multi-linear Diffie-Hellman problem (MDHP, see [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2002/080.pdf) for example). Specifically, for a group $G_1$ endowed with an $n$-multi-linear map $e$ to a group $G_2$ the MDHP is: given $g, g^{a_1}, g^{a_2},\ldots, g^{a_{n+1}}\in G_1$ compute $e(g,g,\ldots,g)^{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n+1}}\in G_2$.

Your problem is clearly no harder than the MDHP for $n=2$ (take $a_1=a$, $a_2=b$, $a_3=b$), and if we can take square roots in either $G_1$ or $G_2$ then a solution to your problem solves MDHP with $n=2$.

To turn your problem into a 2DHP solver in the case where we can take square roots in $G_1$, $a=a_1$ and let $g^{b_1}=g^{a_2}g^{a_3/2}$ so that $b_1=a_2+a_3/2$ and $g^{b_2}=g^{a_2/2}/g^{a_3/2}$ so that $b_2=a_2/2-a_3/2$, then
$$e(g,g)^{ab_1^2}/e(g,g)^{ab_2^2}=e(g,g)^{a_1a_2a_3}.$$

Likewise if we can take square roots in $G_2$ let $b_1=a_2+a_3$ and $b_2=a_2-a_3$, then
$$\left(e(g,g)^{ab_1^2}/e(g,g)^{ab_2^2}\right)^{1/4}=e(g,g)^{a_1a_2a_3}.$$

Note that square roots are easy to take in cyclic groups of known odd order, which covers a great deal of cryptographic applications.